# Postgres turn on log_statement programmatically

Tags: postgresql, logging, psycopg2

I want to turn on logging of all SQL statements that modify the database. I could get that on my own machine by setting the log_statement flag in the configuration file, but it needs to be enabled on the user's machine. How do you enable it from program code? (I'm using Python with psycopg2 if it matters.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of your question. I'm assuming that your machine is running the server that the "user's" machine is running a client of some kind. I am completely flummoxed by your assertion "it needs to be enabled on the user's machine". Unless you want a per-user logfile that resides on the user's machine, the claim doesn't make sense to me. Could elaborate a bit more on what exactly you want to accomplish?

Comment: Right, to clarify, my machine isn't any kind of server, it's just my development box. The server along with the client machines lives at the user's site, which in the general case might be a few thousand miles away and not set up for remote access to files, so manually editing configuration files isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  *"it needs to be enabled on the user's machine"* phrase is confusing, indeed... I assume you  mean *"from the user (client) side"*.

In Postgresql some [server run-time parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-admin.html) can be changed from a connection, but only from a superuser - and only for those settings that do not require a server restart. 
I'm not sure if that includes the many log options. You might try with something like:

```
SELECT set_config('log_XXX', 'off', false);
```

where `log_XXX` is to be replaced by the respective [logging setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT), and `'false`' by the value you want to set.

If that does not work, I guess you are out of luck.

Answer (score 9):

Turning on logging of SQL statements that modify the database can be achieved by:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement TO 'mod';

-- Make it effective by triggering configuration reload (no server restart required).
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
-- To make sure the modification is not limited to the current session scope
-- it is better to log out from postgresql and log back in.

-- Check value of log_statement configuration, expected: mod
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'log_statement';
```

This requires superuser access rights.

Check hereafter links to documentation for more details:

- [ALTER SYSTEM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html)
- [pg_reload_conf()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL)