# RDS Postgres change SQL log_statement value

Tags: postgresql, logging, rds

We use Postgres 9.5 on RDS and have a use case to turn off SQL logging when running bulk inserts. Bulk insert SQL statement is large and not a lot of benefit of logging it since we know it will take more time than our set log_min_duration.

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888589/postgres-turn-on-log-statement-programmatically), I tried doing set_config via psql client. Unfortunately I get permission denied. Logged in user via psql is a member of rds_superuser.

```
SELECT current_setting('log_statement');
┌─────────────────┐
│ current_setting │
├─────────────────┤
│ mod             │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)

SELECT set_config('log_statement', 'mod', false);

ERROR:  42501: permission denied to set parameter "log_statement"
LOCATION:  set_config_option, guc.c:5804
```

Any ideas on why we get permission denied and secondly do folks know if its possible to change this setting at run time in postgres on RDS

Comment: And `rds_superuser` gives you local superuser privileges (check with e.g. `show is_superuser;`)? Because ["*Only superusers can change this setting*"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)?

Comment: thanks @dhke, that was the problem - rds_superuser doesn't grant is_superuser. didn't know about this part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDS uses a different permission model to vanilla Postgres, so the `rds_superuser` role doesn't actually have all the permissions that a "real" superuser would have. In effect, RDS is a "managed" database hosting solution, and full access would give you abilities that would break or compromise that management. Instead, this role is granted [a list of specific permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html).

For most configuration, you have to use what Amazon call "[Parameter Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html)", which are managed through the AWS console or API.

There is a specific page on [logging in Postgres RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html) which gives some examples of using Parameter Groups to set the `log_statement` option.

This means you can't change the setting dynamically in your database connection, e.g. in a `pl/pgsql` function, but you could change it as part of a batch job using [the AWS API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBParameterGroup.html) or [official CLI client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-parameter-group.html).

Comment: thanks. going to accept this answer as it provides answer to permissions part and also whether an app can change log_statement config on RDS or not